# How can I make parameter optional in some but required in other cases in Swagger/PHP?

Tags: php, swagger-2.0, swagger-php

I'm documenting PHP REST-API with Swagger. So I defined my datamodel. My current Problem is, that the required state of some fields varies on different request types. My model looks like this:

```
 * @SWG\Definition(required={"firstName", "lastName"})
 *
 * @SWG\Property(property="id", type="integer", example="5")
 * @property integer $id
 *
 * @SWG\Property(property="firstName", type="string", example="Test Name")
 * @property string $firstName
 *
 * @SWG\Property(property="lastName", type="string", example="Test Name")
 * @property string $lastName
 *
 * @SWG\Property(property="created", type="string", example="2016-11-15 08:05:15")
 * @property string $created
```

- On a post request firstName und lastName are required and id and created are asigned by the api.
- On a put request id is required, but in the url path and firstName und lastName are optional while created can not be changed.
- On a get request all fields are returned.

What a want is:

- Show all fields for get requests.
- Show id as required and show first name and last name as optional on put requests, but don't show created.
- Show first name and last name as required on post request but don't show id and created.

I know I can mark fields as required with required=true but that marks them required everywhere the model is used. The only thing I figured out so far is the required id on the put request, as it is a parameter on it's own.

```
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *          name="id",
 *          in="path",
 *          required=true,
 *          type="integer"
 *      )
```